# Django Mysql Many 2 Many field IN multiple array (at least one match per array)

Tags: mysql, django

My table M2M with this values on Django 1.11:

```
id, m0, m3
1,     1,       1
2,     2,       1
3,     2,       2
4,     3,       1
5,     3,       2
6,     4,       2
7,     5,       2
8,     5,       3
9,     6,       3
10,    6,       4
```

I need to select only products matching M3 id (1 OR 2) AND M3 id (3 OR 4) in Django. Expected result is only product with M0 id 5. Because M0 id:5 has M3 id-> 2 and has M3 id-> 3.

How i can achieve this using Q() ?

This query return zero objects. (i need to query M1)

```
main_query = Q()
main_query &= Q(m0__classifications__in=[1,2])
main_query &= Q(m0__classifications__in=[3,4])
models.M1.objects.filter(main_query)
```

My models:

```
class M0(Basic):
   classifications = model.ManyToManyField('M3')
   ...

class M1(Basic):
   m0 = model.ForeingKey(M0)
   ...

class M3(Basic):
   ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your models? If `product` is a foreign key to something else, then this is quite easy, otherwise this will be quite "painful". Instead of thinking in tables, in Django you should think in terms of models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i added . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This query return zero objects. (i need to query `M1`)

That is because you add both `Q` objects to the same filter, as a result you filter on the *same* related object. That means that your query basically looks like:

> *Give me all the `M1` objects for which there is a related `M0` object with `classifications` in `[1,2]` and classifications in `[3,4]`*.

We are thus talking about the *same* `M0` object, but `classifications can have only one value, and since no elements appear in both lists, indeed we obtain no`M1` objects.

If you are looking for two related `M1` objects for which the first one has a `classification` in `[1,2]` and a (possibly different) related object has a `classification` in `[3,4]`, you can query with:

```
models.M1.objects.filter(
    m0__classifications__in=[1,2]
).filter(
    m0__classifications__in=[3,4]
).distinct()
```

We thus use two `.filter(..)` calls here. The `.distinct()` is used to prevent returning the same `M1` object *multiple* times.

We can use chaining to programmatically add an arbitrary number of sublists, like:

```
sublists = [[1,2], [3,4]]

qs = M1.objects.all()
for sublist in sublists:
    qs = M1.filter(m0__classifications__in=sublist)
qs = qs.distinct()
```

at the end, `qs` is here a queryset, that is the same as the one we "manually" constructed above.

Comment: Ok, but I need to set programmatically this query because the arrays to check can be more than 2. How can I make a dynamic query?

Comment: @cuscode: you can just chain the elements, like `qs = models.M1.objects.all()`, and then `for sublist in mylists: qs = qs.filter(m0__classifications__in=sublist)`. But that being said, this can scale exponentially at the database end, due to the number of `JOIN`s.

Comment: i'm sorry, but this solution is not very good for me beacuse i have a a lot of number of conditions that compose a main_query executed one at the end. Just one of this condition is this case. This is the reason i need to compose this in one dynamic Q() composed.